# create multiple files do loop with java and store in a drive , how to?

Tags: java, makefile

my first java program ..

so I'm trying to create a file and store in my pc using java

```
  import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.io.Writer;


    public class createfile {
        public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {

int[] numbers = {1,2,3};
for (int item : numbers) {
        String key = "file" + item;
        File file = File.createTempFile("c:\\",key,".txt");

        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
        writer.write("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n");
        writer.write("01234567890112345678901234\n");
        writer.write("!@#$%^&*()-=[]{};':',.<>/?\n");
        writer.write("01234567890112345678901234\n");
        writer.write("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n");
        writer.close();
}  
        return file;
    }

    }
```

what am I missing here .. I coudln't figured it out. everything seem to follow along the book.

Thanks

===========update ===========

after I took of

```
- return file ;
- throws IOException ;
- and change to File file = File.createTempFile(key,".txt",new File("c:\\"));
```

I still get this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Unhandled exception type IOException
    Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
    Unhandled exception type IOException
    Unhandled exception type IOException
    Unhandled exception type IOException
    Unhandled exception type IOException
    Unhandled exception type IOException
    Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: No method "File.createTempFile("c:\\", key, ".txt")" aka "(String, String, String) exists in File class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have some mistakes in java syntax:

1. When you declare method as **void** (here public static **void** main(....)) it means that method has no return value - so line `"return file`;" not needed here.
2. Use use wrong signature (wrong parameters types in `File.createTempFile` function.
   Possible usages are:

   - `createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix)`
   - `createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory)`

For additional information about File class use this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Following possible version of working code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;


public class createfile
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {

     int[] numbers = {1,2,3};
     for (int item : numbers) 
     {
        String key = "file" + item;
        File file = File.createTempFile(key,".txt",new File("c:\\"));

        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
        writer.write("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n");
        writer.write("01234567890112345678901234\n");
        writer.write("!@#$%^&*()-=[]{};':',.<>/?\n");
        writer.write("01234567890112345678901234\n");
        writer.write("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n");
        writer.close();
     }  
   }
}
```

You can also see another sample how to write text to file: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/write_to_textfile.html. This link use NetBeans as Java Tool for writing code. I strongly suggest to use some IDE (Eclipse,NetBeans) to write code in java.It will mark your compile mistakes and will suggest corrections. 
NetBeans site:https://netbeans.org/
Welcome to Java world

Comment: I have tried the code but it does not work with me, I still get the IO error :-(

Comment: I updated my answer, please try now.If it willl not work try to point to existing folder, like c:\\myFolder

Comment: THANK YOU !!! after change to c:\\myFolder it works !! I have been struggling with this for 2 full days , Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

`public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {` doesn't return anything, so the `return file` statement is not required

`File.createTempFile` either takes `String`, `String`, `File` or `String`, `String` so `File file = File.createTempFile("c:\\", key, ".txt");` won't compile.

Something like, `File file = File.createTempFile(key, ".txt", new File("c:\\"));` might be a better idea, but is depended on what you want to achieve.

The [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) state that the prefix must be at least three characters long, so you'll need to pad the `key` value to meet these requirements.

You MAY find using something like...

```
File file = new File("C:\\" + key + ".txt");
```

more managable...

Comment: I still get error... Unhandled exception type IOException
 Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
 Unhandled exception type IOException
 Unhandled exception type IOException
 Unhandled exception type IOException
 Unhandled exception type IOException
 Unhandled exception type IOException
 Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: @jpc You need to wrap the write section in a try-catch block